Problem with CSS :valid pseudo-class and required input
I am learning front-end and PHP. I was able to come up with this little form behaving almost perfectly the way I want it.
The problem is, some inputs are not required, that being the case, they are valid even when empty. Because of that, when the page is loaded they already have the classes that should only take form when something is typed. Is there a way around this somehow?


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #01a89e 10%, #006571 90%);
}
.container{
  max-width: 1300px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 1300px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container .text{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #01a89e, #006571, #01a89e, #006571);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.container form{
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.container form .form-row{
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
form .form-row .input-data{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
form .form-row .textarea{
  height: 70px;
}
.input-data input,
.textarea textarea{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.12);
}

.textarea textarea{
  resize: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.input-data label{
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.textarea label{
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}
.input-data .underline{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-data .underline:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.submit-btn .input-data{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45px!important;
  width: 25%!important;
}
.submit-btn .input-data .inner{
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #01a89e, #006571, #01a89e, #006571);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.submit-btn .input-data:hover .inner{
  left: 0;
}
.submit-btn .input-data input{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container .text{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .container form{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  .container form .form-row{
    display: block;
  }
  form .form-row .input-data{
    margin: 35px 0!important;
  }
  .submit-btn .input-data{
    width: 40%!important;
  }
}


input, select {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; 
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.12);
  background: #fff; 
}






.select-container .underline:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}


.select-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.select-container label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.input-data {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.input-data.mid {
  flex: 0.4;
}

.input-data.narrow {
  flex: 0.3; 
}

.input-data.tiny {
  flex: 0.2; 
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.select-container select:focus ~ .underline:before,
.select-container select:valid ~ .underline:before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.input-data select:focus ~ label, .textarea textarea:focus ~ label,
.input-data select:valid ~ label, .textarea textarea:valid ~ label
.input-data input:focus ~ label, .textarea textarea:focus ~ label,
.input-data input:valid ~ label, .textarea textarea:valid ~ label{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3498db;
}

.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before,
.textarea textarea:focus ~ .underline:before,
.textarea textarea:valid ~ .underline:before{
  transform: scale(1);
}

select:focus ~ label, select:valid ~ label {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: transparent; }
input[type=date]:valid::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }
input[type=date]:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }

input[type=date]{ color: transparent; }
input[type=date]:valid{ color: #000; }
input[type=date]:focus{ color: #000; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cadastro de Funcionários</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      Cadastro de Funcionários
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="post.php">
      <div class="form-row">
         <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" id="ctps" maxlength="8" name="ctps" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label for="pis">Carteira de Trabalho</label>
         </div>

         <div class="input-data input-data narrow">
            <input type="text" id="phone" maxlength="14" name="phone">
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label for="phone">Telefone</label>
         </div>

         <div class="input-data select-container input-data tiny">
          <select name="ativo" required>
           <option value="" selected></option>
            <?php
            $query = $pdo->query("SELECT id, ativo FROM ativos");
            $registros = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($registros as $option) {
              echo '<option value="' . $option['id'] . '|' . $option['ativo'] . '">' . $option['ativo'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <label for="ativo">Ativo?</label>
        </div>
 

        <div class="input-data">
          <input type="date" name="demissao">
          <div class="underline"></div>
          <label for="demissao">Demissão</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row submit-btn">
         <div class="input-data">
            <div class="inner"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
         </div>

         <div class="input-data">
            <div class="inner"></div>
            <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



Ideally even the inputs that are not required would only get the :valid css styles if something is typed.

So how are you validating the inputs?

The last part is not something CSS can do since it doesn't actually do the validation. BUT you can style elements that are not required and :valid with :not([required]):valid
